# when assign static variable in a class, would that procedure run everytime we initialize new class?

Tags: static

I have the class

```
class CongNhan
{
    public static decimal pr1= LoadFromDB(query1);
    public static decimal pr2= LoadFromDB(query2);
    public static int pr3= LoadFromBD(query3);

    private string name;

    public CongNhan()
    {
        name = "";
    }

    public CongNhan(string Name)
    {
        name = Name;
    }
}
```

The question is how many times does 3 assigns to the static variables run. And if we new Class like: new CongNhan(), will it call three first assigns.
Because the static variables get value from Database so knowing how many times is it  called is so much important to optimize and make it run faster.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, static members of a class are initialized when app-domain with the class gets loaded into memory. So the three fields `pr1, pr2, pr3` will be initialized once every time app-domain gets loaded. If you new up the class using `new CongNhan()`, those static fields will not be initialized again.